# List machine and user level configuration keys

Tags: c#, windows, encryption, app-config

Does anyone know a way to list the machine-level and user-level configuration keys installed on a machine?

I've created a machine-level key that will be used for the app.config for an application which runs on a server. I know how to export/import, but I'd like to be able to really see that it was installed/imported properly.

I'd be happy with a way to do it in Windows or in .NET code.

Something like the following could (which doesn't throw an exception if "theKey" is not loaded) could be used to check to see if the Provider could be loaded that used the appropriate keyContainerName for a single key ("theKey" in the example). But I'd rather find a way to list the installed/imported keys.

**app.config**

```xml
<configProtectedData>
    <providers>
        <add name="abc"
             type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0,
             Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             keyContainerName="theKey"
             useMachineContainer="true" />
    </providers>
</configProtectedData>
```

**C# code**

```
Configuration myConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
    ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
myConfig.ConnectionStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("abc");
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?  Do you have some relevant code you can post?

Comment: Updated original post.